# How can 8086 processors access harddrives larger than 1 MB?

Tags: memory-management, x86-16, 16-bit, bus

How can 8086 processors (or real mode on later processors) access harddrives larger than 1 MB, when they can only access 1 MB (without expanded memory) of RAM?

Comment: Because hard drives aren't memory mapped. They don't need address space.

Comment: Have a look at the APIs and Interrupts used for accessing drives and you will see that they are addressed on sector level or head / cylinder

Answer (score 3):

Access is not linear (by byte) but by sector. Sector size may be for example 512 bytes. The computer reads sectors to memory as needed.

Comment: How about flash drives then? Are they also divided in sectors? How would the CPU communicate to the hard drives what part it wants to access?

Comment: This is unrelated to addressable memory. Even an 8086 processor could send a 32 or 64 bit offset to a device, whether it is a sector number or a linear index.